# HttpWebResponse send to web browser?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and am making a simple proxy to edit certain headers.

I have used HttpLisenter to get the request and then used HttpWebRequest and Response to edit, send and receive.

Now I need some help to send the edited response back to the web browser. Does anyone have any links or examples? Im stumped :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short example:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create([NEW_URL]);
    request.Timeout = 1000 * 60 * 60;

    request.Method = context.Request.HttpMethod;

    if (request.Method.ToUpper() == "POST")
    {
        Stream sourceInputStream = context.Request.InputStream;
        Stream targetOutputStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        sourceInputStream.CopyTo(targetOutputStream);                
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    context.Response.ContentType = request.ContentType;

    using (response)
    {
        Stream targetInputStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        Stream sourceOutputStream = context.Response.OutputStream;
        targetInputStream.CopyTo(sourceOutputStream);                
    }
}
```

This assume the following extension method is defined (I think using this makes the sample more readable):

```
public static void CopyTo(this Stream input, Stream output)
{
    using (input)
    using (output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        for (int amountRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); amountRead > 0; amountRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, amountRead);
        }                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the response to an html file and then start the browser with a command to open the file.

```
class Program
{
    static int Main() {
        WebRequest wr = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://google.com/");
        HttpWebResponse wresp = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();

        string outFile = @"c:\tmp\google.html";

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wresp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
             using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outFile, false)) {
                  sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
             }
        }

        BrowseFile(outFile);

        return 0;
   }

   static void BrowseFile(string filePath)
   {
       ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
       startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
       startInfo.Arguments = filePath;
       Process.Start(startInfo);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...

That is a good idea but will not really do for what I want.

If I can't do it with HttpWebResponse is there some other function to send data to a web browser?

Thanks

Comment: This is a difficult problem that I can't provide code for. You have to accept incoming http requests from web browsers on your network, make the http requests on their behalf, and return the responses to the original channel.

Comment: Yes its the returning the response to the web browser thats causing the problem.

Could I not use sockets to connect the web browser to my application then use HttpWebRequest/Response from the data sent then send it back that way? If so could someone post links or examples??

Thanks again

Comment: Ok well i have managed to send the response HTML back with HttpWebResponse to the browser but images will show up?

How does the browser read images what format do they need to be for te browser to display then (binary, base64) or am I doing it wrong?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at source code for existing proxy servers.

- [Mini Proxy Server](http://miniproxyserver.codeplex.com/) (c#)
- [Web Proxy Server](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/psingh/web_proxy11162005001036AM/web_proxy.aspx) (c#)